# codeigniter - test controller/method not working

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, putty

I am accessing a Putty server to try and run a method from a controller.

I have a controller inside a `batch` folder named `GetPrefectures`.

The controller's code:

```
<?php
require_once(APPPATH."controller/batch/GetIndustry.php");

class GetPrefecture extends BaseController
{

function __construct()
{
    $this->load->model("PrefectureModel", "prefModel");
}

public function init() 
{
    log_message('test_debug');
    $this->checkSteps();
}

public function checkSteps()
{
    $completed_steps = $this->prefModel->checkStepstbl();

    $this->getList($completed_steps);
}
}
?>
```

I try to add a log message so I know that the controller is working.

Here's how I do it.
after I access the server and locate the path for my file, I enter the code to run the controller.

```
php /var/www/listingapp/public/index.php batch/GetPrefecture init
```

then, I use the logs with this code to check if it is running.

```
tail -n1000 -f application/logs/log-2017-08-25.php
```

But after this, the cmd shows me this as logs:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
DEBUG - 2017-08-25 10:55:46 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2017-08-25 10:55:46 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
```

I cannot see any log message "test_debug", I think it cannot detect the `init`, so this means nothing is running.
How can I do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't look like your PHP is being run. Is PHP running? If necessary, use the absolute path to php, not just "php". Also, it looks like you are on Linux or Mac. Why use Putty when you can just use the terminal?

Comment: already tried "/usr/bin/php /var/www/listingapp/public/index.php batch/GetPrefecture init". I'm using putty because I will later deploy the script on it.

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/php /var/www/listingapp/public/index.php getprefecture init`